# node.js net connect doesn't show error when wifi is off

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node.js client to receive data from aprs T2 server. It works fine when wifi is stable. However, when I turn off wifi manually, it doesn't show any error message. When I turn on wifi again, it doesn't try to reconnect to the T2 server. Doesn't anyone know how to solve this problem?
Here's part of my code:

```
var proxy = net.connect({port:14580,host:'hangzhou.aprs2.net'},function() {
    console.log("connected to server!");
    proxy.write("user BG5ZZZ-92 pass XXXXX ver MY185\n#filter t/poi\n");
});

proxy.on("error",function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    proxy.end();
    proxy.connect({port:14580,host:'hangzhou.aprs2.net'},function() {
        console.log("connected to server!");
        proxy.write("user BG5ZZZ-92 pass XXXXX ver MY185\n#filter t/poi\n");
    });
});

proxy.on('end',function(){
    console.log("proxy unconnected.");
    proxy.connect({port:14580,host:'hangzhou.aprs2.net'},function() {
        console.log("connected to server!");
        proxy.write("user BG5ZZZ-92 pass XXXXX ver MY185\n#filter t/poi\n");
    });
})
```

The client always shows "connected to server!", but no data is received anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no reliable way to detect a dead connection. The OS typically has some settings that change the behavior of how the underlying TCP stack uses keepalive probes to automatically reset the connection. The problem with that though is that more often than not, the timing for these keepalive probes results in a very long connection timeout.

So a better way to check for a dead connection is to use application-level ping messages. If one side sends x amount of pings in y amount of time without any answers to those pings, then you should consider the connection dead and try forcefully reconnecting. This is how OpenSSH implements keepalive for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my program is a client that doesn't send pings. Is there any way to detect a dead connection from the client side?

Comment: If you cannot send your own ping/"null" packets, then the best you can do is use [`socket.setKeepAlive()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay) and either tweak your OS's TCP keepalive settings or write your own C++ binding that sets the appropriate platform-specific keepalive socket options for your `net.Socket`.

Comment: oh, I think I misunderstood your answer at first... thank you!
and in my case, because the server send data to client constantly, I can simply do this that if in y amount of time the client doesn't receive any data, I end the current connection and set up a new one.